# What does it mean for Webpack to ship with runtime?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I heard somewhere that "Webpack ships with runtime" - and that's suppose to mean that Webpack has its own version of requiring modules. I don't understand what runtime means in this context. Does it mean that when you hit your localhost that has Webpack running, it will build out your code into a bundle.js at the moment you hit localhost and figure out right then and there how to all your require and module dependencies will play out?

If so, why is this important? Isn't this the only way webpack can work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that when Webpack builds your Javascript, it also includes a bit of its own code which will get executed at *runtime*. The result of a Webpack build isn't only exclusively your code you piped in, it's your code plus some code that Webpack adds.